# Why in C++ recursion the addresses of stack variables grow backwards?

Tags: c++, clang

Why the addresses of stack variables grow backwards in C++?
If so, what is the benefit of such design?
Is it specific to clang/llvm?

More specifically, when I run the following program,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void f(int n, int* first_v) {
    int v = 0;
    if (first_v == NULL) {
        first_v = &v;
    }
    std::cout << "(offset=" << ((int)&v - (int)first_v) << ") ";

    if (n<=0) return;
    f(n-1, first_v);
}

int main() {
    f(3, NULL);
}
```

the output is

```
(offset=0) (offset=-48) (offset=-96) (offset=-144)
```

(click here http://codepad.org/nTs0jgr3 to run online)

PS. Pardon for not using Modern C++ strictly (Use of `NULL` and `*`), null_ptr was not available in the compiler I was testing.

PS. Q: Is it really backwards, or is it an artifact of conversion of pointer type `int*` to `signed int`?
A: At least we can say the direction of stack is opposite of the conventions for loops/iterators, ie the `++` operator of a for loop that uses a pointer. Which is a convention (ie, a C implementation can compile it backwards).

Comment: C++ has no say over this. This is how the hardware/CPU works. As far as the reason for that, it's historical in nature.

Comment: Comparing the address of objects like this is UB.

Comment: Comparing two pointers that don't point to parts of the same object (in this case, comparing the addresses of distinct `ints`s that have no particular relationship in memory to each other) gives undefined behaviour.   Even ignoring that (for sake of discussion only) converting a pointer to an `int` is not guaranteed to preserve value (or relationship between values) so converting two pointers to `int` and then subtracting is not necessarily meaningful.